# Почему LeakCanary предоставляет зашифрованные имена методов?

Tags: java, android, утечка-памяти, proguard

Используя библиотеку LeakCanary в отчете об утечке памяти я получаю зашифрованные имена методов. Например:

```
static hk.o
references ht.a 
leaks Activity instance
```

Может ли кто-нибудь объяснить этот отчет? Почему он не пишет имена методов, которые я использую?

Я использую версию debug кода без ProGuard.

Вот исходный код.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);

    final ImageButton btn_pas   = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_pas);
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.fci_2)
.placeholder(R.color.white).into(btn_pas);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-...");

    requestNewInterstitial();
}
Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    requestNewInterstitial();
}
private final void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}

public final void pas(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, pas.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены что это ваши методы, а не код какой то библиотеки, которая предварительно была обфусицирована?

Comment: Привел исходный код где найдена данная утечка.

Comment: Этот вопрос лучше задать авторам библиотеки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то утечка связанна с `InterstitialAd`, а это часть Google play services, исходный код которых закрыт и, соответственно, обфусцирован. В этом вы можете убедиться попытавшись просмотреть исходники в Android Studio. Поэтрму и LeakCanary показывает такие имена методов.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что библиотека держит ссылку на активити после поворота, скорее всего она качает рекламу в этот момент:

```
new InterstitialAd(this);
```